# How to permit SSH connexion to a docker container with complete prompt?

Tags: docker, ssh, openssh, tty

I try to deploy **debian containers** to allow users to connect to them over SSH (for students for exemple).

I managed to do this but when I am connected to the container I have a **pseudo-TTY** and it's not the expected result I want. I want to have a complete interactive shell like when we connect to a reel server or machine.

I tried several ideas like :

- change the docker add options in my `docker run` commands like : `docker run -d -it CONAINER_ID`
- change the `sshd_config` in the debian container to allow TTY
- change my dockerfile many times
- add `ssh` options when I connect : `ssh -t` or `ssh -tt`

But any of theses ideas seems to help me.  I show you my current Dockerfile it can be helpfull.

```
FROM debian:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openssh-server && apt-get install -y sudo nano 

RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd

RUN service ssh start

RUN useradd -m john && echo "john:john" | chpasswd && adduser john sudo

EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

So can any one tell me if I can change or do something to resolve this problem please ? Thanks

Comment: This system-administration question sounds like it might be better addressed with a fleet of virtual machines, rather than single-process Docker containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with adding just one option in my Dockerfile when I create the user :

```
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash john && echo "john:john" | chpasswd && adduser john sudo
```

Now, when I log into the container with SSH, I have a fully complete SHELL.

Answer (score 0):

When you do the docker run command is there an option to map the local port (say 8212 to the container's port 22?

Typically, even when you expose an http or https port you have to provide a mapping:

```
$ docker run -d -p 81:80 --name httpd-container httpd
```

So I think you would need to map a port to be able to access the one in the local container.

Comment: it's not the problem because I am already able to connect to my container with the IP address of the container : ssh john@X.X.X.X       so the problem is to have a complete TTY in the container

Comment: if you log into the container "running bash on it" and do an 'service sshd status' what is returned?

Comment: **service sshd status**  returns  'unrecognized service' but **service ssh status** returns 'sshd is running'